# Simultaneous primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Wikipedia says that the pair $(m, m+2)$ are simultaneously prime iff $$4((m-1)! + 1) \equiv -m \mod m(m+2)$$

which I imagine is easily proven using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Wilson's Theorem.  I was wondering if there is a generalization to more simultaneous primes, each of the form $am+b$.  My own attempts have gotten quite messy.

Comment: It is much easier to check the numbers one by one. Note that Wilson's criterion is not very useful for finding or verifying large primes.